# Make PostgreSQL request on a WFS in JS

Tags: postgis, geoserver

I am making a map using layers stored in a PostgreSQL (PostGIS) database. I am using GeoServer to successfully load layers with Leaflet in WFS format, but I wonder how to make SQL request on it through my JavaScript code.

How can I do that ?
Or more generally, how can I can simply connect to a PG database within a JS script ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't send SQL directly but GeoServer allows you to apply a filter to your GetFeature request as either an [OGC filter](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/filter/function.html#wfs-filtering) (as all WFS do) or as a [CQL filter](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wfs/vendor.html#cql-filters).

GeoServer then translates as much as possible of that filter to SQL to pass to PostGIS and handles the rest seamlessly for you.

Comment: I don't really understand your answer but I gonna have a look.
From what I've read so far, process to connect to a PG database may look like this  :

const { Client } = require('pg')
const client = new Client({
  host: 'my.database-server.com',
  port: 5334,
  user: 'database-user',
  password: 'secretpassword!!',
})

I tried but I got error at first line for require('pg').

Comment: You shouldn't connect to PG directly, just add the filter to the WFS getFeature request

Comment: Alright, but with your method, how can you iterate through lines of a PG table ?
In my case, I would need to get each property of the features in a JS loop...

Comment: Your filter is sent to PG to restrict which features are returned no need to iterate anything

Comment: Yes but the features are returned into a map format. I would just like to get the features as a JS matrix.

Answer (score 0):

You can't connect to server-side database via JavaScript. You should either use Geoserver to handle your request, or use another server-side language to handle it through webservices, such as Java Spring boot, php, Node.js, etc.

For example, if you want to search an area, you can write a webservice on the server-side and call it by JavaScript, and then handle the returned data to be shown on the map as tables for example.